# Can query an elasticsearch index to find unique values of a field while filtering on another field?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

I'd like find all unique set values of field3 that roll up under a specific value of field1 and a specific value of field2.

I've tried collapsing on field3 but it gives me the error that no mapping was found for that field in order to collapse on.

I need a query that works like this, however this query just gives documents for that filter and not the distinct values for field3:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "field1": "value1"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "field2": "value2"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "timestamp": {
              "gte": "now-4d",
              "lte": "now"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs" : {
    "langs" : {
        "terms" : { "field" : "field3",  "size" : 500 }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: are you looking for cardinality aggregation?
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html

Comment: @MusabDogan I'm not just looking for cardinality, but for a list of the actual distinct values.

Comment: @MusabDogan I've tried collapsing on the field3 but it says there's no mapping to collapse on

Comment: Can you share your index mappings for those fields? I think that might play a big role. That's probably why your 'collapse' didn't work!